# jquery - poll json and disable/enable page

Tags: jquery, html, json

For every 5 mins , I am polling some url and getting json response .
If the response gives the status as "ok" then I need to allow the user to see the page otherwise the should be blur or disabled for the user.Upon this a message has to be shown.I have the code for  polling and getting the response.Can anyone help me on blur/disable page and show warning message over the page?

```
(function poll() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/server/api/function",
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("polling");
            },
            dataType: "json",
            complete: poll,
            timeout: 2000
        })
    }, 5000);
})();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `done` and `fail` Promise methods.

```
(function poll() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/server/api/function",
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("polling");
            },
            dataType: "json",
            complete: poll,
            timeout: 2000
        }).done(function(){show user the goods})
          .fail(function(){$( "#target" ).blur()})

    }, 5000);
})();
```

Comment: Can you give the complete code for .fail(function(){blur function})

Comment: I could if I knew exactly what you wanted to blur. From the documentation, you'd want to do something like `$( "#target" ).blur();`

Comment: Thanks . I want to disable/greyout the complete page but blur() function is not taking care of this when I do document.blur ..any idea?

Comment: Basically, what I want to achieve is , i need to stop the user click on the page .

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?